# java profiling for cloudsim

Tags: java, cloudsim

I am simulating a very large trace file from Google data using CloudSim. The simulations takes very very long time to complete (Simulating one day data needs 2 days to complete and simulation 3 days data takes more than 15 days). I profiled my code for methods that takes more time and found that the following methods are more time consuming.

```
    java.lang.Object.wait (more than 50% self time)
    org.cloudbus.cloudsim.core.CloudSim.cancelAll (22% self time)
    java.util.TreeMap.successor (18% self time)
```

Any one have some idea to solve the issue? I dont know where the wait method is called.

Comment: How can we say if we don't see any of your code?

Comment: I am using CloudSim, a free available simulation toolkit.

Comment: So you didn't wrote any code. In that case I misunderstood, because I though CloudSim is a library your code is using.